# sqldf, csv, and fields containing commas

Tags: r, sqldf

Took me a while to figure this out. So, I am [answering my own question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

You have some .csv, you want to load it [fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r/1820610#1820610), you want to use the `sqldf` package. Your usual code is irritated by a few annoying fields. Example:

```
1001,     Amy,9:43:00, 99.2
1002,"Ben,Jr",9:43:00, 99.2
1003,"Ben,Sr",9:44:00, 99.3
```

This code only works on *nix systems.

```
library(sqldf)
system("touch temp.csv")
system("echo '1001, Amy,9:43:00, 99.2\n1002,\"Ben,Jr\",9:43:00, 99.2\n1003,\"Ben,Sr\",9:44:00, 99.3' > temp.csv")
```

If try to read with

```
x <- read.csv.sql("temp.csv", header=FALSE)
```

R complains

```
Error in try({ : 
  RS-DBI driver: (RS_sqlite_import: ./temp.csv line 2 expected 4 columns of data but found 5)
```

The `sqldf`-[FAQ.13](http://code.google.com/p/sqldf/#13._How_does_one_deal_with_quoted_fields_in_read.csv.sql_?) solution doesn't work either:

```
x <- read.csv.sql("temp.csv", filter = "tr -d '\"' ", header=FALSE)
```

Again, R complains

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 1 did not have 5 elements
```

In fact, the filter only removes double quotes.

So, how to proceed?

Comment: I have clarified and improved the FAQ and have included a gawk version of your perl code with a link bank here.

Comment: I initially had confused you with someone else and you must have seen it just before I had fixed the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl and regexes to the rescue. Digging through SO, and toying with regexes [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), it is not too hard come up with the right one:

```
 s/(\"[^\",]+),([^\"]+\")/$1_$2/g
```

which matches `"...,..."`, here the dots are anything but double quotes and commas, and substitues the comma with an underscore. A perl one-liner is the right filter to pass to sqldf:

```
x <- read.csv.sql("temp.csv", 
        filter = "perl -e 's/(\"[^\",]+)_([^\"]+\")/$1_$2/g'", 
        header=FALSE)
```

Here is the dataframe `x`

```
> x
    V1       V2      V3   V4
1 1001      Amy 9:43:00 99.2
2 1002 "Ben_Jr" 9:43:00 99.2
3 1003 "Ben_Sr" 9:44:00 99.3
```

Now, DYO cosmesis on strings ...

**EDIT**: The regex above only replaces the first occurrence of a comma in the field. To replace all the occurrencies use this

```
s{(\"[^\",]+),([^\"]+\")}{$_= $&, s/,/_/g, $_}eg
```

What's different?

1. I replaced the delimiters `/` with `{}`;
2. The option e at the very end, instructs the parser to interpret the replacement field as perl code;
3. The replecement is a simple regex replace, that substitutes all "`,`" with "`_`" within the matched substring `$&`.

An example:

```
system("touch temp.csv")
system("echo '1001, Amy,9:43:00, 99.2\n1002,\"Ben,Jr,More,Commas\",9:43:00, 99.2\n1003,\"Ben,Sr\",9:44:00, 99.3' > temp.csv")
```

The file temp.csv looks like:

```
1001,                 Amy,9:43:00, 99.2
1002,"Ben,Jr,More,Commas",9:43:00, 99.2
1003,            "Ben,Sr",9:44:00, 99.3
```

And can be read with

```
x <- read.csv.sql("temp.csv", 
       filter = "perl -p -e 's{(\"[^\",]+),([^\"]+\")}{$_= $&, s/,/_/g, $_}eg'", 
       header=FALSE)
> x
    V1                   V2      V3   V4
1 1001                  Amy 9:43:00 99.2
2 1002 "Ben_Jr_More_Commas" 9:43:00 99.2
3 1003             "Ben_Sr" 9:44:00 99.3
```

Comment: On `adding filter` argument in read.csv.sql function it gives me error `Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message:In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpcbqrz6\filee4819344504': No such file or directory.` I am writing the cmd in RStudio `x <- read.csv.sql("D:/d/myfile.csv", sql="Select * from file where agent='agnt1455' ",filter = "perl -e 's/(\"[^\",]+)_([^\"]+\")/$1_$2/g'") `

Answer (score 0):

For windows, sqldf now comes with **trcomma2dot.vbs** which does this by default with read.csv2.sql . Although found it to be slow for very large data.(>1million rows)

It mentions about "tr" for non-windows based system but I could not try it.

Comment: Note that `trcomma2dot` translates all commas to dots, not just ones in quotes.